# jQuery filtering content using multiple data attributes stored in an array

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have been struggling to get round an issue with filtering multiple data attributes that I have stored in an array.
I have 2 different filter types (filter topic and filter content type) topics being article topics and type being video or post etc.
I am using data-attributes on the articles to manage these different types of filter.

So from there I have a click event looking at different li elements on the page, these have the data attributes assigned to them also.

```
<li class="filter-pill" data-category-type="Arts & Creative Industries">Arts & Creative Industries</li>
<li class="filter-pill" data-category-name="Video">Video</li>
```

I store this data in an array and then show the articles that match the array data. However when clicking the first filter nothing shows until the second filter (video or post) is clicked.

I need to be able to filter by AND and OR and can not work this part out.

Here is a fiddle of all my code
https://jsfiddle.net/dfwpmLt6/

Comment: This line `return filterArray.includes($(this).data('category-type')) && filterArray.includes($(this).data('category-name'));` says you have to have *both* type and name selected - if either filter is unselected, you get nothing.

Comment: Off topic: note that your UI category type/name are the opposites of the data- type/name attributes.

Comment: Updated the UI the category type/name to match

Comment: When I use OR it displays all the video articles but ignores the category

Comment: I think you should move the `push` to the `filterArray` to the `else` block.

Comment: Does this help you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lr34teap/ ?

Comment: unfortunately not as when you click a category type and then click category-name video it should display only video articles for that category type

Comment: That would just require changing the `toggle` condition to be an `&&`: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/cg256kwt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say, "I need to be able to filter by AND and OR", what I understand you to mean is this:

- If some Names and some Types are selected: show the articles whose Name and Type are *both* selected.
- If some Names are selected, but no Types: show the articles whose Name is selected, regardless of Type.
- If some Types are selected, but no Names: show the articles whose Type is selected, regardless of Name.

If this understanding is correct, I think it will be very difficult to accomplish is tracking the selected filters in a single array. This is because we need to check separately if any names are selected as well as any types. My recommendation would be to store these selected filters separately. For example:

```
const selectedFilters = {
  names: [],
  types: []
};
```

We would then need to update the logic that updates the `selectedFilters`:

```
const changedFilters = {
  names: $this.data('category-name'),
  types: $this.data('category-type')
};

['names', 'types'].forEach(key => {
  if (!changedFilters[key]) { return; }
    
  const value = changedFilters[key];
  const index = selectedFilters[key].indexOf(value);
    
  if (index > -1) {
    selectedFilters[key] = selectedFilters[key].slice(0, index).concat(selectedFilters[key].slice(index + 1));
  } else {
    selectedFilters[key].push(value);
  }
});
```

Finally, we loop through each `.article-child` and determine whether to show or hide it (using jQuery's [.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method). The logic will filter by Name *only if* there are selected Names and will filter by Type *only if* there are selected Types:

```
$('.article-child').each(function () {
  const $this = $(this);
  const categoryName = $this.data('category-name');
  const categoryType = $this.data('category-type');

  let isVisible = true;
  if (selectedFilters.names.length) {
    isVisible = isVisible && selectedFilters.names.includes(categoryName);
  }
  if (selectedFilters.types.length) {
    isVisible = isVisible && selectedFilters.types.includes(categoryType);
  }

  $this.toggle(isVisible);
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/cg256kwt/) is an example fiddle.

Comment: This is great thank you, I have created 2 arrays and then used if and else if statements but I think the function will be more efficient.